# how to expose oracle pl/sql api's as web services in oracle ebs 11.5.10?

Tags: web-services, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

how to expose oracle pl/sql api's as web services in oracle ebs 11.5.10? i've read that in oracle ebs r12 there is soa gateway. unfortunately my client will be sticking with 11i version for a couple more years so i'm stuck with it.

does anyone have any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: You say which version of EBS.  But when it comes to PL/SQL what matters is the version of the database.  Oracle 11g has pretty good support for native PL/SQL web services.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the tip. But we are currently on Oracle 10g version.

Comment: @APC, can you provide a link if someone is on 11?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is available for your version of EBS but

> The [Oracle Integration Repository](http://irep.oracle.com/index.html) is a compilation of information
>   about the numerous service endpoints exposed by the Oracle E-Business
>   Suite of applications. It provides a complete catalog of Oracle
>   E-Business Suite's business service interfaces. The tool lets users
>   easily discover and deploy the appropriate business service interface
>   for integration with any system, application, or business partner.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by following the steps below:
Use the tools like jDeveloper to expose the API as a web-service
and then register it in EBS to use it.